# Ignoring argument in maphash lambda function

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have the following, I'm iterating over a hashmap using maphash. The lambda function that process each element in the hashmap receives two arguments, a key and a value. But I never use the value, so, when compiling I receive a warning. How can I fix this warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
? (defun foo (a b) (+ a 2))
;Compiler warnings :
;   In FOO: Unused lexical variable B
FOO

? (defun foo (a b)
    (declare (ignore b))
    (+ a 2))
FOO
```

Answer (score 2):

Rainer's already point out the `(declare (ignore ...))` (which was already present in another question, actually).  If you're interested in another way to iterate over hash table keys (or values), you can use [**loop**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_loop.htm):

```
(let ((table (make-hash-table)))
  (dotimes (x 5) 
    (setf (gethash x table) (format nil "~R" x)))
  (values 
   (loop for value being each hash-value of table
      collect value)
   (loop for key being each hash-key of table
      collect key)))
;=> 
; ("zero" "one" "two" "three" "four")
; (0 1 2 3 4)
```